# Udev error while upgrading

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, udev

I update and upgrade my ubuntu 14.04 server. Update is successfull but i get this error while upgrading :

```
apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up udev (204-5ubuntu20.3) ...
 * udev requires hotplug support, not started
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please run `export LC_ALL=C` and run the command again, now with english messages - and edit your answer with it.

Comment: It's done, in english now,

Comment: Did you solve it? I have same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Same here! 30 minutes of digging and I found this:

```
$ apt-get download udev
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-confmiss udev_204-5ubuntu20.9_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Worked for me. For more info go to [Dimitri's comment in Ubuntu's bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1377624/comments/12).

Comment: Had same problem on VPS, this worked for me, thanks.